# fetching 10 digits from 16 digits number where we have to omit exact 10 digit number which is also there

Tags: python, regex

CSV file:

```
Header  ---> | Name   | date       | Serial | ref1             | ref2

1st Row ---> | ABC    | 2019-12-12 | MKK4   | 8030000000000000 | 1234567890
```

Python:

```
number = re.findall(r'(\d{10})', line)
```

The above code fetches both the 8030000000 and 1234567890. but I want to fetch only the 8030000000 from the 16 digit number and skip the exact 10 digit number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to find the first ten digits of any sixteen digit number, an easy way is

```py
>>> import re
>>> line = "ABC 2019-12-12 MKK4 8030000000000000 1234567890"
>>> re.findall(r'(\d{10})\d{6}', line) 
['8030000000']
```

That is, match any sequence of 10 digits followed by 6 digits, and return the first 10.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  i used r'(\d{10})\d[0-9]' .